Comparing Electric Potential Energy of two Charges

I do not know what I am missing here and would appreciate a little help in figuring out the flaw in my logic. I have a row of positive charges and a row of negative charges as shown in the image above. I am arguing that charges placed at A and B, 'Both are the same sign assume they are both positive', have the same electric potential energy. My reasoning is if we we wanted to move the charge A against the electric field (to A') we have to overcome the strong repelling forces of the +ve row and the weak attracting force of the -ve row. Similarly, if we want to move charge B to B' we need to overcome the strong attraction forces of the -ve row and the weak repulsion forces by the +ve row. Now I do not get why A has higher electric potential energy than B. Both charges are the same sign assume they are positive.

What are the charges of particles A and B? Are they the same sign, or opposite sign?

Both are the same sign assume they are both positive

Are the charges equal?

In the case that A and B both have the same positive charge: remember that potential energy associated with a position (it is not defined as something that requires two positions e.g. A and A') is the amount of kinetic energy the particle would get if allowed to move freely from that position to a set zero-point (if possible; if not then it is minus the kinetic energy from the zero point to the position).
In this case, both particles would move down under the influence of the electric field, so we set the zero point at the bottom. We then have a situation where A would have more kinetic energy when reaching the bottom than B, hence A has more potential energy.
A side note: it seems you are using capital letters to refer to both the particles, and the positions of the particles. Remember that potential energy is a property of a particle (an object), and its value depends on the position of the particle (a property of an object).

You can calculate the energy of the charges explicitly. For simplicity, let us reduce the problem to a one-dimensional case. Take fixed charges $-Q$ at $z=-a/2$ and $+Q$ at $z=a/2$. These act as the bottom blue and top red charges in your figure. Take a test particle of charge $q$ at some height $-a/2<z<a/2$. The interaction energy of two charges $q_1$ and $q_2$ placed at a distance $d$ is given by
$$E = \frac{q_1 q_2}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 d}.$$
Thus you total energy is given by
$$E = \frac{Qq}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 (a/2-z)} + \frac{(-Q)q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 (a/2+z)} = \frac{Qq}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \frac{2z}{(a^2/4)-z^2}$$
You can see that the values of total energy for $z=z_0$ will be more than that for $z=-z_0$, since the function is monotonically increasing in $z$ for the range considered. Intuitively, you can see this as a result of the fact that the electromagnetic interaction energy is not a linear function of distance. Rather, it drops as the inverse distance between the charges. It is much easier to bring a (positive) test charge from infinity and place it near a negative charge than a positive charge. Hope that helps.

The change in electric potential energy for a positive charge going from position $A$ to position $A'$ is the same as the change in electric potential energy for a positive charge going from position $B$ to position $B'$ provided $AA'=BB'$ and the magnitudes of the charges is the same.
Assume all the charges are at rest.
If the positive charge at position $A$ is released then it will accelerated downwards gaining kinetic energy whilst losing electric potential energy.
When the positive charge reaches a position $B''$ at the same horizontal level as position $B$ it has lost electrical potential energy and its electrical potential energy is now the same as the charge at position $B$.
Thus the electric potential energy of a charge at position $A$ is greater than the electrical potential energy of a charge at position $B$.

From your picture the potential has by approximation left-right symmetry and top-down antisymmetry. Therefore the potential difference V_A'-V_A=V_B'-V_B. If the charges are equal then the corresponding potential energy differences are also the same.
